# Visual Studio Git - HEAD & Master branch under remote/origin

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-tfs

I have not created local branch while making changes. I used master branch that gets created locally and made commit & sync changes after modifying few things.

Now, I see there are two branches that got created in remotes/origin, HEAD and master. Initially before doing this commit, I used to see only one i.e. master branch under remotes/origin. 
So, want to know ---

1. what is HEAD branch for
2. and whether I can delete it.
3. And, was that created on the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

HEAD is not a branch it is a reference or pointer to the most recent commit in the current branch.

Check out this [post](https://wilsonmar.github.io/git-head/).